# WebUSB print HTML formatted content

Tags: html, image, printing, webusb

I am able to use JavaScript with WebUSB to print text only to a POS printer. Anyone knows how to print HTML or image? Plain text printing is useless. An article from this link https://www.visuality.pl/posts/webusb-print-image-and-text-in-thermal-printers appears to be the right answer but it doesn't tell the definition of "image" for the function printImage(image), and how to generate the "image" data. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the rest of the code in that article it looks like `image` is a 3-dimensional array where the first two dimensions are the x and y coordinates and the last is just 3 elements for red, green and blue.  Take a look at the definitions of `calculateSlice()` and `calculateLuminance()` and you'll see what I mean.

I don't know what you mean by weird symbols in the code. It looks fine to me.

To understand how their code works I recommend checking out their [previous article](https://www.visuality.pl/posts/thermal-printer-protocols-for-image-and-text) because it explains the commands that the printer supports and so why it is they are reformatting the image the way they are.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I removed the "weird" phrase. Just need to know how the "image" can be generated. I had read the "previous article" before asking. But the key part is not how the "image" is structured. It is how the "image" is created/prepared for function printImage(image). I could use the combination of TextEncoder and/or Blob FileReader, canvas.toDataURL etc methods to generate image data. But how would that data be further formatted for printImage(image) remains unknown. It should be a matter of a few short lines of code I think.

Comment: There isn't a good way to render HTML content into a bitmap but if you have a <canvas> tag you can use [getImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) to get an instance of the [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) interface which provides the raw pixel values you can feed into `printImage()`. Note that the format provided by `ImageData` is slightly different and you probably want to just rewrite the existing code to use its one-dimensional array rather than a three-dimensional array.

Comment: I was also trying getImageData function and feel it is just getting closer. It prints 27,56 on paper. The sample data yielded by getImageData is  

 ImageData {data: Uint8ClampedArray(80000), width: 200, height: 100}

 where
 data: Uint8ClampedArray(80000)
  [0 … 9999]
  [10000 … 19999]
  [20000 … 29999]
  [30000 … 39999]
  [40000 … 49999]
  [50000 … 59999]
  [60000 … 69999]
  [70000 … 79999]

I modified manipulateImage with
 const imageWidth =image.width; 
 var img=image.data;
 ...
  data.push(...collectStripe(x, y, img));
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The solution from https://www.visuality.pl/posts/webusb-print-image-and-text-in-thermal-printers does not work eventually. And it won't be easy to crack it.

Instead of fiddling with machine code for unproven solution here is a small plugin that works. https://github.com/NielsLeenheer/EscPosEncoder